# Как убрать текст из сайдбара в коротком описании поста?

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт на WordPress.

Текст из сайдбара отображается в коротком описании поста (except) на главной странице.

Почему и как убрать?

Comment: В сайдбаре нет никакого текста (это область для виджетов) и даже или бы и был - он не может отображать в анонсе. Ты о чем-то другом говоришь.

Comment: покажите хоть скриншоты того, что вас волнует